# How to detect swipe from Touch and Mouse and find swipe direction

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, mousemove, touchstart

I am trying to build a carousel using CSS and jQuery.

However, I want to add swipe events for easy user experience..

I found a code snippet promising swipes using mouse and touch.

After heavily Modifying it, I tried to use it for my Carousel...

It works on Mobile, but doesn't work on Desktop (tried on Windows 7, Google Chrome)

Here's the code

```
    document.addEventListener('touchstart', handleTouchStart, false);        
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMove, false);

    var xDown = null;                                                        
    var yDown = null;

    function getTouches(evt) {
        return evt.touches || evt.originalEvent.touches;
    }                                                     

    function handleTouchStart(evt) {
        console.log('start');
        const firstTouch = getTouches(evt)[0];                                      
        xDown = firstTouch.clientX;                                      
        yDown = firstTouch.clientY;                                      
    };                                                

    function handleTouchMove(evt) {
        console.log('move');
        if ( ! xDown || ! yDown ) {
            return;
        }

        var xUp = evt.touches[0].clientX;                                    
        var yUp = evt.touches[0].clientY;

        var xDiff = xDown - xUp;
        var yDiff = yDown - yUp;

        if ( xDiff > 0 ) {
            jQuery('.CarouselNext').click();    
        } else {
            jQuery('.CarouselPrevious').click();
        }                       
        xDown = null;
        yDown = null;                                             
    };
```

I read that for compatability with Mouse, I need to use `mousestart` and `mousemove`

I tried, to change the first 2 lines like this:

```
    document.addEventListener('mousestart', handleTouchStart, false);        
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleTouchMove, false);
```

It doesn't work...

Not even on Android/iOS

I am told that this is because, I am not able to find the swipe direction properly using mousestart.

Please suggest.

Comment: I'd recommend using a touch gesture javascript library like [HammerJS](https://hammerjs.github.io/recognizer-swipe/).

Comment: Too heavy for using it just once... My company is over demanding in terms of JS libs used. I agree that could have saved me time, but their logic is : why add a JS lib of 7.3kb, when same can be done in 1.5kb haha.... still would appreicate your suggestions on how to implement it

Comment: You could give [this](https://jsfiddle.net/6fydcoe4/) a try, after changing the first variable to whatever you named your carousel.

Comment: @Shikkediel Thanks buddy, it worked well, (with some modifications) thanks